# Refactor ternary to if-block programatically

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there a way through the context menus to refactor a ternary assignment into one that is done with an `if-else` block?

So, for example you'd have something like this:

```
$a = ($b > -32)? "up" : "down";
```

You'd then apply this transformation, and PHPStorm would magically change it into:

```
if ($b > -32) {
    $a = "up";
} else {
    $a = "down";
}
```

Seems like a really common and easily automated operation, so it must be automated somewhere in this labyrinth of menus.

Comment: *"Seems like a really common and easily automated operation"* common? Hmm .. usually doing other way around... In any case: there is an Intention to perform such conversion in both directions. Problem is: batch fixing can only be applied to problematic places (i.e. a place to which specific Inspection is pointing). As we all know -- both ways are actually good code... so I do not see how such intention can be applied in a batch. But sure -- "Code | Inspect code" and see if IDE will pick up anything there (any "fixes" to specific issue will be listed under "light bulb" icons).

Comment: I wanted this by use case case was deminifying javascript code that had horrible nested ternery like so `video ? video.getPaused() ? video.play() : (video.pause(), d.a.set("pauseCount", d.a.get("pauseCount") + 1)) : (ne(".PlayerControls--button-control-row").children().eq(0).trigger("click")`. But I guess this is only because someone else already destroyed the intent of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHPStorm 8 can do it with Alt-Enter shortcut. Put your cursor at the `?` operator and key in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

As I am using PHPStorm 10 right now when I was trying to turn a simple `if` and `else` into a ternary operator I could select my code as I have shown in this little screen shot below:

[image]

Then I clicked on that little bulb or you can use `alt + return` to choose `Simplify If` and if my code could be simplified with ternary operator then it will become one as I have shown in the screenshot below otherwise the IDE will not show you any output message:

[image]